# In php exec function can't put a variable's value in an INSERT statement

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to add a row to my table `video_games` by using the value of a `$_GET` like this:

```
$yourname = $_GET['yourName'];

$bdd->exec('INSERT INTO video_games(name, owner, console, price) VALUES($yourname, \'Patrick\', \'PC\',45)');
```

But I get this error:

> Unknown column `$yourname` in `field list`

I tried several other solutions like `$name` or `name` or `'name'` instead of `$name`. But I can't have the value of `$_GET` to be inserted.

I have also checked other posts and I did not find any solution, yet it should be a famous question.

To make it simple, the problem is: How to put the value of a variable in an `INSERT` statement using the `exec()` function ?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but duplicate of which other question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this....

```
$yourname = $_GET['yourName'];

$bdd->exec("INSERT INTO video_games(name, owner, console, price) VALUES('$yourname', 'Patrick', 'PC',45)");
```

Comment: Yes, and I get a Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\'Patrick\', \'PC\',45)

Comment: no need to `\'Patrick\'`.just use like `'Patrick'`